# Magento 1.8.1 shipping and payment method

Tags: magento-1.8, upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I just upgrade Magento to 1.8.1 version, and have problem with my shipping and payment method. In my previous 1.6.2 version i used to use this modules:

- CashOnDelivery
- Auctionmaid_Matrxrate
- Mymonki_Ship2pay

On 1.8.1 the only working ext is `Auctionmaid_Matrxrate`.

Is there any modules who can do that:

Shipping:

- Multiple Table Rates
- Store pickup
- Free delivery

Payment:

- Bank transfer
- **No option** (if someone want to pick the product from store)
- Cash on delivery

Now the only shipping and payment things I have are: multi table rate, free delivery and bank transfer

Answer (score 2):

The Matrixrates module should meet your requirements for all of your shipping options.

For the payment options, you could use the existing Magento payment options such as check and rename it. Or you could make your own simple payment method. There are a couple of tutorials around...

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method

Comment: It is a good idea to use Matrixrates for all shipping method, but how to hide payment method if someone want to pick the product from store?

Comment: I would suggest something like: http://www.magestore.com/magento-store-pickup-extension.html 

Store pickup has some other requirements that should be addressed, such as store address etc. If its a simple version follow the http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/ tutorial, and you should be able to create a no cost, store pickup Shipping method.